# Дополнить скрипт смены даты

Tags: javascript

можно ли дополнить как то данный скрипт? Суть этого скрипта, что он показывает дату следующего дня. Можно ли его как то дополнить, что бы в субботу он показывал дату понедельника? (грубо говоря пропускал дату воскресенья)

```
document.querySelector("a[href='data']").setAttribute("id", "day");
document.querySelector("a[href='data2']").setAttribute("id", "day2");
var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
document.getElementById("day2").innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
```

```
<a class="tn-atom" href="data" id="day"></a>
<a class="tn-atom" href="data2" id="day2"></a>
```

Comment: а праздники что

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector("a[href='data']").setAttribute("id", "day");
document.querySelector("a[href='data2']").setAttribute("id", "day2");
var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
  day, month, year;
if(currentDate.getDay() !== 0) {
  day = currentDate.getDate()
  month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
  year = currentDate.getFullYear()
  document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
  document.getElementById("day2").innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
} else {
  currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  day = currentDate.getDate()
  month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
  year = currentDate.getFullYear()
  document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
  document.getElementById("day2").innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
}
```

```html
<a class="tn-atom" href="data" id="day"></a>
<a class="tn-atom" href="data2" id="day2"></a>
```

Метод getDay() показывает с воскресенья, по этому проверка на ноль. Удачи :)